# Hoptoad v. Exceptional v. exception_notification v. exception_logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

Which of the following exception notification solutions is the best?

1. [Exceptional](http://getexceptional.com/)
2. [Hoptoad](http://hoptoadapp.com/)
3. [exception_notification](http://github.com/rails/exception_notification/tree/master)
4. [exception_logger](http://github.com/defunkt/exception_logger/tree/master)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032143/rails-users-what-exception-notification-software-do-you-use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use hoptoad and have had nothing but a positive experience, I highly recommend it.

Comment: I much prefer the hoptoad UI, but exceptional is a Heroku add-on, so I often end up using it

Comment: Hoptoad is now also available as a Heroku add-on

Answer (score 1):

On a high traffic site we use an internal messaging queue for errors, then pump those back up to hoptoad. Not a massive fan of hoptoad, it's too easy to ignore messages.

The internal queue makes it nice and easy to change service if we need to, and prevents our app from being dependant on an external application within a request cycle (we log some errors to hoptoad even if the overall request is successful.

Just thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

We are working really hard at the moment to make Exceptional the best exception tracker out there so we think you'll like it if you give it a try. If you do manage to evaluate it, and have some time to give us your feedback during your evaluation we would really appreciate your thoughts.

You can signup for a free 'starter' plan at http://getexceptional.com

If you have any questions during your evaluation please let us know at feedback@getexceptional.com

cheers,

Wal
walter@getexceptional.com

Comment: how do we sign up to this starter plan the link is not obvious and your blog links are broken in the footer

Answer (score 0):

We use Hoptoad and it works well. There are some features that I really miss in its UI though like full text search and ability to close multiple errors in the list view via checkboxes. I would be curious what advantages Exceptional has over Hoptoad and if its approach is different.

Answer (score 0):

We got one more which is free and very cool.

it's free for many projects.

Checkout http://errorapp.com

Comment: The project seems to be good, but it was discontinued, unfortunately.