# Error catching, Monitoring and Notification for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, monitoring, ping

Sorry for the broad question, but I'd really like to know the combination of services people are using to get great monitoring for their apps.  Right now, I'm thinking of going with Pingdom + Hoptoad (+ PagerDuty), but I want to know what others are using as pretty much everything I'm deciding between has several competitors.

I want to know when my app is unreachable, unstable, or down

I want to do basic sanity check that my app is good (renders something), but doesn't have to be deep (no need to simulate a log in for a 'ping')

I want to be able to cheaply and easily add new things to monitor

I want to be able to generate my own notifications (Seems pretty standard now, but worth calling out)

I want to know when I get a lot of exceptions (the odd one here and there I'm willing to check in the morning, but 1 every few min is worth getting up for)

I want reporting

It needs to scale with multiple apps, apps running across multiple nodes, and with multiple users on the same projects.

I've seen the [Hoptoad vs. Exceptional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358315/hoptoad-v-exceptional-v-exception-notification-v-exception-logger) discussion.  I'm more interested in what people have put together to form their entire monitoring suite.  What are you using?  What do you like about it?  What do you not like about it?

Would really love to get suggestions!

Comment: No answers :(  What I've been going with uptimerobot, hoptoad, pager duty, and new relic (free), and some home grown metrics. I've get phone calls when my site goes down, and I can see some metrics in new relic, and dig into errors on hoptoad.  Maybe people can suggest alternatives to those products?

Comment: That's probalbly because you've answered your question already. At the company we use Nagios, Hoptoad, Monit and Pingdom to make sure everything is working. Fortunately there is no magic on this, most of these tools just work and you get used to live with them. We also have some specific checks to see if our resque queues are backed up but that's pretty much it.

Comment: I guess I was kind of hoping there were better solutions

Answer (score 6):

These are the tools we use for monitoring:

**Monit: http://mmonit.com/monit/**
 For both internal & external monitoring: apache, nginx, mongrel, mysql, sphinx, delayed_job, postfix, CPU, etc
 Whenever a process goes down, its will try to bring it up. If it is not able to start a process it will notify us.

**Cloudkick: https://www.cloudkick.com/**
 For both internal & external. We are in the process of evaluating this tool. It supports rackspace, ec2, slicehost, etc. If you use more than one cloud services, this tool might help you.

**Alert Grid: http://alert-grid.com/**
 For monitoring our cron tasks.

**Exception Notification:**
  Error App: http://errorapp.com/ - Its free
  Airbrake(hoptoad) http://airbrakeapp.com/pages/home

**Logwatch:**
  http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logwatch8.html - Sends daily report about whats happening in a server. Like new packages installed, list of cron tasks running, authentication failures, etc.

**Intrusion Detection:**
  http://www.ossec.net/

Answer (score 4):

The rails error management landscape has changed a lot since this question was first posted. But this thread came up when I was doing google searches for airbrake alternatives.

Several new companies have started offering error monitoring services for rails. The one we like at work is [Honeybadger.io](http://honeybadger.io). [Paper trail](https://papertrailapp.com/) is also a nice service in this space.

Answer (score 3):

Another option for error tracking and monitoring in Rails is **Raygun**, at http://raygun.io - it's got the usual complement of features like intelligent email notifications and error grouping, but adds nice organisation support for multiple devs and integration in GitHub, Fogbugz, YouTrack etc. It's also got Hipchat notifications so when an exception occurs your team sees it in your chat room.

Installing and setting up the ruby gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/raygun4ruby) into your project's pretty quick, too.

Answer (score 1):

One wonderful way to get updates about your application is to use [Exception Notification](https://github.com/rails/exception_notification).

This allows you to get emails based on exceptions that take place in your app. It won't be a solution to all of your information desires, but if someone tries to access a non-existent page, you could get information about what they tried to access, how they got there, etc.

Comment: This is not practical for us because we're running at scale. When we introduce a bug, we hit it thousands of times. The error handling services provide us with aggregation of our errors which is immensely valuable.

Comment: Have you looked into AirBrake?

Answer (score 1):

Hoptaud and Exception Notification are good, Heroku has another addons to use like StillAlive.

FogBugz and LightHouseApp may also help you, Lighthouse is free for open-source.

If you want to get involved deeply in Rails errors and notifications read The Rails 3 Way book's first chapter and /environment folder's content.

The best way is still BDD and TDD. Work out all redirections, add nice 404 page, use all stages for development (devel, test, hopefully staging and QA too, and only finally production), then get notifications and always check logfiles before going for production. HTH